# Kinect Camera Yaw Movement

Tags: c++, kinect

I am developing kinect project with c++.

When we run 'Face Tracking Visualization' Kinect sample, it tracks my face.
However, if my face position is not located center, cameras(maybe I think) in Kinect body change the yaw for positioning the center of view to face.

How to move change the yaw of camera? I'm not talking about `NuiCameraElevationSetAngle(-27-27)`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinect does not have a "pan" [feature](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4ad3a714-f1e4-4c06-91cf-6ddbef11557e/can-the-kinect-pan?forum=kinectsdk). When I wanted to implement this feature I was going to buy a motor and brackets, then manually program them to turn to the person's face. On [SparkFun](https://www.sparkfun.com/news/720) there is even a tutorial on this, except with OpenCV and a normal webcam, so some minor code modifications will be needed.